# Is it possible in Scala to have two methods with identical signatures in the one class?

Tags: scala

I would like to write a library such that clients could write code such as the following. It's in pseudo Scala since I don't know if it is syntactically possible

```
class ClientCode {

    historical {
        override def onTrade() { // historcal processing here}  
    }

    override def onTrade() { // real time processing here }
}
```

Basically what I would like to do is send trade data to the client.  There is both historical and real time data which have different business rules.  Syntactically I would like everything to be handled by onTrade().  I could do something like the following

```
override def onTrade() {

    if (historical) { } ...
    else {} 

}
```

However the historical rules are short and optional compared to the long and mandatory live rules so I find the above syntax a bit cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a trait

```
trait Historical extends ClientCode {
  override def onTrade() { ... }
}
```

and then

```
val c = new ClientCode with Historical
```

to use the overridden `onTrade()`.  Is that enough?

Comment: Does this force a single implementation of onTrade?  I would like the client to be able to generate two separate implementations with the exact same signature in a single class.

Comment: This does work with a single implementation.  The JVM does not support two methods with exactly the same signature in the same class.  You either need two classes, or you need different methods (at least with overloaded arguments).  Since what you want is, strictly speaking, impossible, I was wondering if the above was good enough.